# Property 'y' doesn't work when using GSAP in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I'm trying to implement horizontal scroll by GSAP and when it's triggered, want to make some tags(*which are .anim in the codes*) move down. For this, I used *y: -130* in GSAP but it doesn't work. But other properties that I used with like opacity and duration work well. Can you let me know the reason only *y: -130* doesn't work??

If you see CodeSandBox, You can check opacity changes but y doesn't

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Wrap } from "./styles";
import One from "../components/one/One";
import Two from "../components/two/Two";
import Three from "../components/three/Three";
import { gsap, ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/all";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const Page = () => {
  const wrapRef = useRef(null);
  const oneRef = useRef(null);
  const twoRef = useRef(null);
  const threeRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sections = gsap.utils.toArray([
      oneRef.current,
      twoRef.current,
      threeRef.current
    ]);

    const mask = document.querySelector(".mask");

    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      let scrollTween = gsap.to(sections, {
        xPercent: -105 * (sections.length - 1),
        ease: "none",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: ".container",
          pin: true,
          scrub: 1,
          end: "+=3000"
        }
      });

      //here is the problem part
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        let text = section.querySelectorAll(".anim");

        gsap.from(text, {
          y: -130,
          opacity: 0,
          duration: 2,
          ease: "elastic",
          stagger: 0.1,
          scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: section,
            containerAnimation: scrollTween,
            start: "left center",
            markers: true
          }
        });
      });
    });

    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container" ref={wrapRef}>
          <One ref={oneRef}></One>
          <Two ref={twoRef}></Two>
          <Three ref={threeRef}></Three>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**Child Component**
*.anim* is the target I want to animate
and I used *const text* in Parent component to use *.anim*

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { Wrap } from "./styles";

const Two = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Wrap ref={ref}>
      <div>
        <span className="anim">Two</span>
      </div>
      <div className="nor">2</div>
    </Wrap>
  );
});

export default Two;
```

CodeSandBox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontalscroll-test-dzqh8k?file=/src/page/Page.jsx